# upgrading pyudev issue

Tags: centos, python, pip

I'm trying to update `pyudev` package from 0.15 to 0.16.x or higher, but the following message displays:

```
$ sudo pip install pyudev 0.21.0 -U
Collecting pyudev
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a2/31a07829acea8e70a28c247f43fa5d981229ae0f9edfeddedf52de00709b/pyudev-0.21.0.tar.gz
Collecting 0.21.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 0.21.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for 0.21.0
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

**NOTE:** Same thing happens with `dnspython`.

Answer (score 0):

You're entering the command in wrong format. Valid requirement specifiers are:

- `packagename`
- `packagename==version`
- `packagename>=version` (or `<=`)
- `packagename>version` (or `<`)

Add the `==` sign for the exact version specifier:

```
$ pip install pyudev==0.21.0
```